# How to read a local .sql file into R

Tags: mysql, r

I don't know if this question has been asked before but I am wondering if there is a direct way of reading .sql files into R without creating a mysql connection using RMySQL or other packages. Is there a command that can work as easily as `read.table(myfile.sql)` without building a connection?